# Friendly_id create slugs for a existing model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I have Locations models - countries/regions/cities which have in total 50k plus records. i have added the configuration to these models.

Is there a way through the command line i can create the slugs for these models at one go instead of editing and saving all the models.

Comment: why would someone down vote it? if they have an answer please share it :/

Answer (score 7):

**Save**

To help you further - `@iceman` is right - you need to loop through your `slugged` models & save them again. [`friendly_id` recommends this](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#rails-quickstart) by doing it in the `rails console`:

```
$ rails c
$ Location.find_each(&:save)
```

This should help Rails load each of the items, and then save them immediately. This will trigger the `slug` generation functionality of `friendly_id`, populating the `slug` columns of your `Location` records

Answer (score 4):

friendly_id updates the slug on save-ing. I did it like this for my project, but that only included about 5k items, so this works but could take some time depending on your setup.

```
Model.all.map(&:save)
```

Comment: @HarshaMV Thru the command line as you were talking about :) `rails c`

Comment: hehe :D am confused. whats the first line and the rest of the block. do i need to run both?

Comment: i tried doing that. also added this in the model http://pastebin.com/HRpfijAS but still it doesnt update

Comment: @HarshaMV Try `Model.first.save!`, with `!` you'll get an exception, maybe it will bring you closer to a solution. There must be something missing in your setup.

Comment: for an "Image" model, it does not do anything on my side. the slug never updates on an existing record